# Are U(H) and PU(H) locally uniform topological groups with the norm topology? Towards an instance of infinite-dimensional Hilbert's Fifth Problem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-groups, banach-manifold

In looking at the work of Enflo generalising Hilbert's Fifth Problem from the Euclidean to the Banach case, there are the following conditions:

- the multiplication in the topological group is locally uniformly continuous (aka a "locally uniform group");
- right translation is (Fréchet) continuously differentiable.

I was hoping to use some of this technology to prove that a topological group $Q$ with underlying space a Banach manifold was in fact a Lie group. But the group multiplication is only defined implicitly via a non-specified homeomorphism of underlying spaces, $Q \simeq Q'$ where $Q$ is a Banach manifold and $Q'$ is a topological group. There is a closed normal subgroup of $Q$ that is a Banach Lie group so that the quotient is definitely locally uniform (it is in fact a Lie group)—and this subgroup is $PU(\mathcal{H})$ with the norm topology. So if have any hope of applying some version of what Enflo did via showing $Q$ locally uniform, I'd better have $PU(\mathcal{H})$ locally uniform. But this I don't know. Perhaps it's true just from general theory, but unfortunately I don't know enough here.

As a bonus question, if someone particularly well-versed in Hilbert's Fifthyology comes along: given that I know there is a *smooth* local section of $Q \to Q/PU(\mathcal{H})$ defined in a neighbourhood of the identity element is this enough to bootstrap up to get $Q$ a Banach–Lie group? Getting the translation to be continuously differentiable seems mysterious to me.

Comment: "[...] a topological group with underlying space a Banach manifold was in fact a Lie group" -- Do you mean to ask whether any topological group whose underlying topological space is homeomorphic to a Banach manifold is the underlying topological group of a *Banach*-Lie group? I guess not, since by the Anderson-Kadec theorem, any two separable infinite-dimensional Fréchet spaces are homeomorphic. So is your $Q$ some specific topological group? If so, could you give some more context on where the conditions you name come from?